# What does a "Blended IP" mean in terms of speed?

Tags: hosting, network-speed, colocation

I'm getting a server colocated at a facility and they stated the internet speed will be `10 Mbps Blended IP on 100 Mbps Network Port`. What does blended IP mean?

Comment: It means speed which can be customized for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blended IP generally means Blended BGP (Multi-Carrier)

It's a form of a semi-redundant circuit across multiple providers.

You can see exactly what those carriers are by taking your assigned IP and putting in into lg.he.net or similar services, Or ask what carriers are used.